# Loop in coffee script?

Tags: coffeescript

I'm translating a piece of code from javascript to coffeescript.

```
  for (var i = 0, len = keys.length; i < len; i++) {
    k = keys[i];
    if (!mailOptions.hasOwnProperty(k))
      mailOptions[k] = app.set('mailOptions')[k]
  }
```

I have no idea how to approach to it and on the doc website is not clear, can someone give me a clear explanation? thank you very much!

Comment: Be careful using `hasOwnProperty` in this way; it'll fail if there happens to be a mail option named "hasOwnProperty". To handle this case correctly, use `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(mailOptions, k)` (or `Object::hasOwnProperty.call mailOptions, k` in CoffeeScript).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for key in keys
  if not mailOptions.hasOwnProperty key
    mailOptions[key] = (app.set 'mailOptions')[key]
```

Or guard-style:

```
for key in keys when not mailOptions.hasOwnProperty key
  mailOptions[key] = (app.set 'mailOptions')[key]
```

Compiles to:

```
var key, _i, _len;

for (_i = 0, _len = keys.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
  key = keys[_i];
  if (!mailOptions.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    mailOptions[key] = (app.set('mailOptions'))[key];
  }
}
```

Comment: The guard style is preferable here (imo). For what it's worth, `(app.set 'mailOptions')[key]` would more commonly be written as `app.set('mailOptions')[key]`, though of course the lispy style is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way (from here: http://js2coffee.org/):

```
i = 0
len = keys.length

while i < len
  k = keys[i]
  mailOptions[k] = app.set("mailOptions")[k]  unless mailOptions.hasOwnProperty(k)
  i++
```

But I wouldn't do it this way. I would just do:

```
for k in keys
  mailOptions[k] = app.set("mailOptions")[k] unless mailOptions.hasOwnProperty k
```

This outputs the following (excluding `var`, which it also outputs):

```
for (_i = 0, _len = keys.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
  k = keys[_i];
  if (!mailOptions.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
    mailOptions[k] = app.set("mailOptions")[k];
  }
}
```

Or, if you wanted to be fancier, which I don't advise in this situation, since it sacrifices some readability:

```
(mailOptions[k] = app.set("mailOptions")[k] unless mailOptions.hasOwnProperty k) for k in keys
```